# Two left join in one query to Joomla database

Tags: joomla-3.x, development, joomla-api, mysql

I have two tables: #__records and #__parents. In the first table some records may have parent records that are stored in the same table but relations between childs and parents are stored in the second table. For example

**#__records:**

```
id  name
1   Child1
2   Child2
3   Parent1
```

**#__parents**

```
id  child parent
1     2    3
2     1    3
```

Now I have the query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('a.id, a.name')
    ->from('#__records as a');
$query->select('b.parent as parentid');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__parents AS b ON b.child = a.id');
$db->setQuery($query);
return $query;
```

It returns the names of records (a.name) but with IDs of parents (b.parent). I need the second "left join" or another way to get the names of parents instead of their IDs. Something like:

```
select c.name as parentname from #__records as c where c.id=b.parent
```

Comment: If you would like to see a solution that employs recursion to identify parent rows that are one or more "generations" above, please update your question to provide sample data with at least a grandparent relationship among three rows and express how you would like the output to be prepared.  Performing recursive queries is a mega-bad idea as Lanah stated below.  The tables should be wholly transferred to php for recursive processing.  Seem overwhelming?  We are here to help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$db = JFactory::getDBO();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select('a.id, a.name, c.id as parent_id, c.name as parent_name')
    ->from('#__records as a');
$query->select('b.parent as parentid');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__parents AS b ON b.child = a.id');
$query->join('LEFT', '#__records AS c ON b.parent = c.id');
$db->setQuery($query);
return $query;
```

You definitely can do multiple left joins. Just alias the table to a different alias ('c' in this case) and then have the select also alias the columns they aren't the same as what you are pulling for the child.

Comment: Thank you, works! Just edit the alias **parent_id** to **parentid** i.e. without underscore in the first select method as it's in the second one

Comment: But how to be if record has many parents? Now with your code I get the same record many times in the list for each parent_name. How to push the parent_name to array()?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do "many to many" connections it's better to catch table A and B into PHP and then do the operators, but if you need only if A table is relative to C based on B table, the other answer is good ; )